# How can I build my SQL query from these tables?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm thinking of building query from these 2 tables (on SQL Server 2008). I have 2 tables as shown below:

Table 1

```
 MemberId  . MemberName .  Percentage .  Amount1
 00000001    AAA                 1.0     100
 00000002    BBB                 1.2     800
 00000003    ZZZ                 1.0     700
```

Table 2

```
 MemberId  . MemberName .  Percentage .  Amount2
 00000002    BBB                 1.5     500
 00000002    BBB                 1.6     100
 00000002    BBB                 1.6     150
```

The result I want is

```
 MemberId  . MemberName .  Percentage .  Amount . NettAmount
 00000001    AAA                 1.0      100     100
 00000002    BBB                 1.2      800      50 <-- 800-(500+100+150)
 00000002    BBB                 1.5      500     500
 00000002    BBB                 1.6      250     250
 00000003    ZZZ                 1.0      700     700
```

50 comes from 800 in Table1 minus sum of Amount2 in table2 for MemberID=00000002

Plz someone help me to build the query to reach this result.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why does the subtraction only get applied to `BBB, 1.2` and not the other `BBB` percentages?

Comment: I agree with Martin...MemberId will be used as the KEY.

Comment: I would have expected `500` off the `1.5` row. `0` off the `1.2` row and `250` off the `1.6` row. Is that an acceptable result? Also this doesn't look normalised MemberName should probably be in a members table and what is the relationship between the percentages in the 2 tables? If a `memberid, percentage` is in `tableB` should there always be a matching one in `tableA`?

Comment: @Martin; those columns in table2 are used for subtraction from column amount1 in table1 regardless of  percentage or others columns.

Comment: @marc_s; i'm sorry. it's typo.

Comment: @marc_s; ok! you are absolutely right. it's my stupid mistake again. it should be 250 both in amount and nettAmount in table result. it comes from group by percentage in table2 actually.

Comment: @Vee: a tip for next time: try to make sure your post is accurate and responders don't have to first "debug" your post to understand your logic.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is something like this:

1. Select from Table1
2. Do a GROUP BY select from Table2
3. Join the results of those two queries by MemberId

SQL code:

```
SELECT ... FROM Table1
INNER JOIN (SELECT MemberId, SUM(Amount2) FROM Table2 GROUP BY MemberId) Agg
ON Table1.MemberId = Agg.MemberId
```

Then you should be able to select "Amount1 - Amount2" from the join.

HTH.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: +1 Though you'd probably use an `outer join`, and `Amount1 - IsNull(Amount2,0)`

Comment: ok guys! i got a solution. I got an idea from John and Andomar. Thank you everyone.